# Problems with Xalan using XPATH (unclosed tags)

Tags: xpath, htmlunit, xalan

Greetings,

I'm facing a problem with the following tech-stack: JWebUnit -> HtmlUnit -> Xalan.
I'm trying to find an element by XPATH, but the HTML document is pretty malformed.

Xalan stops finding elements when I reach the `/body` element on XPATH. I believe it's because the document contains two `<body>` tags and one being unclosed.

Everything works for `/html/head` or `/html`. But when I try `/html/body` (or `/html/body[1]`, `//body[1]`, or anything inside those tags) I get only null from Xalan.

Is there any way to get around with that? I just can't change the html document istself. Thank you kindly for your attention.

Best regards,
Thiago

Comment: Strange! If you can run this `/html` Xpath expression, it should be posible to run another one as well.

Comment: I can run /html expression all right. Anytime it returns me the HTML element. But when I try any expression that goes further html/body it loses itself and returns null. I believe it's because the document has two <body> tags and one being unclosed!

Comment: You should be not able to run an XPath query over a not well formed tree.

Answer (score 1):

HtmlUnit must be using something to convert HTML to XML. Perhaps you can tell it to use jsoup or tagsoup, which are very tolerant of messy HTML?

You might as well also write code to just dump the XML tree to a file so you can see what's in it.

Comment: Hum JSoup is quite interesting. Not sure if I can tell HtmlUnit to use another API without modifying/rebuilding the source. But I'll take a look! Thank you!